# How do I convert a basic server code that exposes a few REST endpoints and provides static response into an ear and deploy it in a lightweight server?

Tags: java, rest, server

I have written an interface and an implementation class - which exposes a few REST endpoints (eg. /mock/abc/user) and returns some static values as json response. How do I bundle these code into an ear/war and deploy them in a lightweight standalone server such as Wildfly.

**Interface**

```
@Path("/mock/server")
public interface MockServer{

       @Path("/user")
       @GET
       @Produces({MimeTypes.APPLICATION_JSON})
       Response getUserDetails();
}
```

**Impl Class**

```
public class MockServerImpl implements MockServer{
    @Override
    public Response getUserDetails() {
    ...
    }
```

I am supposed to deploy it in a separate server and hit these endpoints from my JUnit tests.

Comment: Are you explicitly looking for a standalone server? As you can write unit tests without doing so, see https://www.baeldung.com/jersey-test for example. You absolutely do **not** need to first deploy your code into some EAR/WAR/WHATEWAR/... you can do a "full" REST request call right out of JUnit ... when using such a framework.

Comment: @GhostCat Unfortunately, yes. The high-level view of this project is to increase code coverage for some complex server code that hits Netlify APIs. My task is to mock the Netilfy server responses with a server that gives the static response and write tests to increase code coverage for the server code.

Comment: Well, then just turn to your favorite search engine and search for "wildfly demo application" ... http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/resteasy/wildfly-hello-world/ ... thing is: you are expected to do research before posting your question. Do you actually think you are the first person wondering how to deploy a service with wildfly? Wildfly even has their own github with just that: examples! https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart ... so, there is really no need to ask people here to write down *another* tutorial for you.

Comment: And note, that isn't meant to be an attack. Just an observation: almost all basic things are covered somewhere. It should always be your first impulse to search for tutorials for example. Asking other people to explain stuff that is documented slows you down, too.